# devise_invitable does not send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

it is the first time using devise_invitable gem
,there is no error and no emails sent

**projects_controller.rb**

```
def add_admin
      @email = :email
      User.invite!(:email => @email, :project => current_user.project)
  end
```

**views/projects/show.html.erb**

```
<% if @project == current_user.project %>
  <% @user = User.new %>
  <%= "you can add admin to " + @project.project_name %>
  <p> please type his email </p>
  <%= form_for @user, url: {controller: "projects", action: "add_admin"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.email_field "email" %>
    <%= f.submit "Invite" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
post "/projects/add_admin"
```

Comment: Have you set up your mailer properly? Try sending and receiving mails manually first.

Comment: it sends email while user registration normally.

Comment: Maybe you just never jump into the if execution block: try this: <% if @project.id == current_user.project.id %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found it

the method should be

```
  def add_admin
      User.invite!(:email => params[:user][:email], :ProjectId => current_user.project.id)
  end
```